# Quicksort recursion depth Stack space of O(n) doesnot cause stackoverflow?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

In Worst case Quicksort recursion Depth requires Stack  space  of  O(n). Why it doesn't cause a stack overflow for large set in the worst case? (reversed sequence)

Comment: A quicksort implementation that uses the first element as a pivot is a terrible one. Note that the better approach is to randomly take an element or select the middle element as the pivot.

Comment: @amit: taking the middle element as pivot is also terrible, it's just less terrible because it's harder to construct the killer input.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I disagree. Note that a random array has exactly the same change of being "worst case" with any selection - as a random selected element. The problem with selecting the first element is - the probability of a real life array to be sorted (or almost sorted) is NOT `1/n!` (how many times have you seen a code where an already sorted array is resorted? too much...), while I doubt the probability of the worst case array when chosing the middle element will be much greater then `1/n!` if any.  That said - if you are afraid of *attacks* - then any arbitrary selection should be avoided.

Comment: Possibly the difference between us is just that I think I should by default be afraid of attacks, and you think by default you shouldn't. We might even both be correct, it just depends what context you're writing for, but I do think that for a general utility operation like sorting it is incredibly rare to be able to rule out that attacks might be made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you recurse on both sides of the pivot then it does cause stack overflow for sufficiently large data in the worst case. That's why nobody uses a naive QuickSort in production code.

There is a simple change you can make to the algorithm to prevent `Omega(n)` worst-case stack use. After each partition, recursively Quicksort the "small half" and then iteratively loop around to do the "big half". This requires `O(log n)` additional stack space. If you want to, you can make it `O(1)` stack space and `O(log n)` additional non-stack space by modifying this again. Push the "big half" onto the end of a pre-allocated array (or other last-in-first-out data structure of your choice), loop around to do the "small half", and when you hit bottom pop the last element off the data structure to do next.

There are further changes you can make to avoid `Omega(n^2)` worst-case runtime. But then it's not a naive QuickSort any more, it's a QuickSort-with-median-of-medians-pivot-selection, or an Introsort, or whatever.

Comment: QuickSort-with-median-of-medians-pivot-selection is still quicksort, and still exhibits the same worst-case behaviour for some input.

Comment: @Konrad: No so. Median of medians is a true linear time selection algorithm, and its pivot selection algorithm (which is what you'd use in quicksort) finds a pivot between the 30th and 70th percentile of the data, which is good enough to avoid the worst cases of both QuickSort and QuickSelect. Are you thinking of "median-of-3", which does have killer cases albeit requiring some tricky construction?

Comment: You’re right of course. I read this as median-of-median-of-three which is a different (constant-time) method.

Comment: @Konrad: I think at least one of the references I used the first and last time I wrote a quicksort for real use (c. 2001) called that pseudo-median-of-9. Maybe to avoid exactly that misreading.

Answer (score 2):

> Then Why it doesnot causes stack overflow for large set of data of order in worst case

It does. Why would you assume that it doesn’t?

(But note that the worst case input for quicksort depends on the pivot you chose. It’s not generally the reversed sequence – and in fact, for a naive choice of pivot another worst-case input is an already sorted sequence, it doesn’t have to be reversed.)

But library implementations of sort algorithms are actually rarely quicksort nowadays, precisely for this reason. For instance, the C++ [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) uses [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) instead, which is a modified quicksort that will switch to a different sorting algorithm as soon as it recurses too deeply.

Answer (score 1):

It could cause a stack overflow in the case of a reversed sequence (the worest case). Because an array could be too large for the internal function stack. (99,000,000 elements, for example) You could just replace recursion with a `stack` data structure. You will loop `while (stck.empty() == false)`

```
function quicksort(arr[0,1,...n-1])
     stack.push(pair(0, n - 1))
     while stack not empty
          interval = stack.pop()
          ...
          ...
          stack.push(interval(0, pivot - 1))
          stack.push(interval(pivot + 1, n - 1))
```

Comment: That wasn't the question. And although it stops stack overflows, it doesn't improve the O(n) space consumption, which is a serious problem.

Comment: @delnan The problem of `O(n)` stack space is highly dependant on the sorting case. It varies between better cases and worse casaes

Comment: @delnan: that was *exactly* the question, which is solely about stack overflow. Maybe the questioner should also be concerned about non-stack additional space requirement, but in fact did not ask about it.

Comment: @SteveJessop The question ask "Why it doesn't cause a stack overflow for large set in the worst case? (reversed sequence)". While that seems to be a flawed premise, an answer should at least address it.